# Validator message and icons are at the center of an input element in Angular Mdb

Tags: bootstrap-4, material-design

I can't figure out why my validator message and icons are at the wrong place. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Pleas see my code below:

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="mask rgba-black-light flex-center">
  <div class="container text-center white-text">
    <div class="card" style="background-color: transparent; ">
      <div class="card-body">
        <!--Title-->
        <h4 class="card-title">Register</h4>
        <!--Text-->

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
          <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="card">


                <!--Card content-->
                <div class="card-body">

                  <!-- Subscription form -->
                  <form [formGroup]="subscriptionForm">


                    <div class="md-form">
                      <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                      <input type="text" formControlName="subscriptionFormName" id="subscriptionFormName" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
                      <label for="subscriptionFormName">Your name</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="md-form">
                      <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                      <input type="email" id="subscriptionFormEmail" formControlName="subscriptionFormEmail" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
                      <label for="subscriptionFormEmail">Your email</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center">
                      <button class="btn btn-indigo waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Send
                        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  <!-- Subscription form -->



                </div>

              </div>


            </div>






          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!--card-->
  </div>
  <!--container-->
</div>
```

Below is what it looks like when I render it.
[image]

As you can see the error message is misplaced and also the icons. Your help is always appreciated.

Comment: The raw HTML you have provided doesn't seem to display the problem. Can you please add your relevant CSS as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The css is built-in in the angular material bootstrap. I didn't add any custom css rules.

Comment: I got this working by removing the `text-center` class in the container.